How to setup a mDNS in Rust for both registering and discovering?
I have two Rust programs in two devices. They communicate with each other via TCP. Since these two programs will distribute, I don't want to specify the IP address in the configs, rather I want to use mDNS to let the client auto find and connect to the server (with zero config).
I don't want to use Rust crates that require extra installation like Apple Bonjour etc. I also want the mDNS task to be an async task (compatible with tokio runtime).
I have tried some crates but failed to implement.
My current solution:
For registering device, I am using crate [libmdns = "0.9"]:
use linmdns::Responder;
use tokio;

pub async fn mdns_register() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let responder = Responder::new()?;
    let _svc = responder.register(
        "_mytype._tcp".to_owned(),
        "MyService".to_owned(),
        8686,
        &["path=/"],
        );
    loop {
        tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(10)).await;
    }
}

For discovering device, I am using crate [mdns = "3.0"]
use mdns::{Record, RecordKind, Error};
use futures_util::{pin_mut, stream::StreamExt};
use std::{net::IpAddr, time::Duration};

pub async fn mdns_discovery(server_address: &mut Option<IpAddr>) -> Result<(), Error> {

    let stream = mdns::discover::all("_mytype._tcp", Duration::from_secs(10))?.listen();
    pin_mut!(stream);

    while let Some(Ok(response)) = stream.next().await {
        let address = response.records().filter_map(self::to_ip_addr).next();
        if let Some(addr) = address {
            if server_address.is_none() {log::info!("Service found at {}", addr);}
            *server_address = address;
        } else {
            log::info!("Service not found, will retry in 10s.");
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn to_ip_addr(record: &Record) -> Option<IpAddr> {
    match record.kind {
        RecordKind::A(addr) => Some(addr.into()),
        RecordKind::AAAA(addr) => Some(addr.into()),
        _ => None,
    }
}

When I run these two programs, I never succeed in discovering the service. Instead the discovering device keeps showing warning of "LabelIsNotAscii".
What is the problem in my code? Should I use other mDNS crates? Or is there any better solution other than mDNS for zero config TCP connection? Thanks!
